# If $P \in \mathbb{R}_2[X]$ and $\phi (P)=P(1)$, then how do I find the base of $Ker(\phi)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

In the correction I am given:

> $P \in Ker(\phi) \iff \phi(P)=0 \iff P(1)=0 \iff (X-1)$ divides $P$

So far so good, then it goes:

> We can conclude $Ker(\phi)= \left \{ (aX+b)(X-1) | (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \right \}$

And I fail to understand how can we deduce this. Can someone see the reasoning behind?

Comment: $Ker(\phi)$ consists of all polynomials of degree 2 such that $\phi(P) = 0$, which is exactly what you have on the second highlighted line.

Comment: But why isn't it simply then $Ker(\phi)= P \in \mathbb{R}_2[X], P(1)=0$?

Comment: Because it is an alternative description. To say that $P(1)=0$ is the same as saying that $P$ is a multiple of $(X-1)$.